# Doing more than 1 thing in a iter().map()

Tags: rust, iterator

I would like to use a map to create a new vector, but at the same time, do other things inside that map. I'm working on Advent of Code 2021, day 6 part 1.

This code loops through a vector and decrements all the values by one. If the value is at `0`, then it resets that position to `6` and adds an `8` to the end of the vector.

```
fn run_growth_simulation(mut state: Vec<u8>, days: i32) -> usize {
    for _day in 0..days {
        let mut new_fish = 0;
        state.iter_mut().map(|x| match x {
            num: u8 @ 1..=8 => {num - 1},
            0 => {new_fish += 1; 6},
            _ => unreachable!()
        })

        for _fish in 0..new_fish {
            state.push(8);
        }
    }
    state.iter().count() as usize
}
```

How do I return the right item from the closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would mutate the value in the iterator directly and not build a new array, because of that use `for_each` instead of `map` (or **preferable** directly a for loop).
Then inside the match statement mutate the value:

```rust
state.iter_mut().for_each(|x| match x {
             //: u8 removed because it gave me an syntax error
                            // mutate the number directly (we have to use `num` because x was moved)
            num @ 1..=8 => {*num -= 1;},
                                 // mutate the number
            0 => {new_fish += 1; *x = 6;},
            _ => unreachable!()
        });
```

A slightly different approach would be to count the `0`s in the vector, remove them, subtract each value by 1 and add the new fish

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to the answer stating that `for_each()` is preferable to `map()` here (since we don't consume what `map()` emits), below is a simpler example trying to illustrate the problem (and why the borrow-checker is right when it forbids such attempts).
In both cases (`test1()` and `test2()`) we are iterating over a vector while we are extending it (this is what was intended in the question).

In `test1()` the iterator considers the storage for the values once for all when it is created.
For all the subsequent iterations, it will refer to this initial storage, thus this storage must not move elsewhere in memory in the meantime.
That's why the iterator borrows the vector (mutably or not, this is not important here).
However, during these iterations we try to append new values to this vector: this may move the storage (for reallocation purpose) and **fortunately** this requires a mutable borrow of the vector (then it's rejected).

In `test2()` we avoid keeping a reference to the initial storage, and use a counter instead.
This works, but this is suboptimal since at each iteration this index operation (`[]`) needs to check the bounds.
The iterator in the previous function knows the bounds one for all; that's why iterators lead to better optimisation opportunities by the compiler.
Note that `len()` is evaluated once for all at the beginning of the loop here; this is probably what we want, but if we wanted to reevaluate it at each iteration, then we would have to use a `loop {}` instruction.

What is discussed here is not specific to the language but to the problem itself.
With a more permissive programming language, the first attempt may have been allowed but would have lead to memory errors; or such language should shift systematically towards the second attempt and pay the cost of bound checking at each iteration.

In the end, your solution with a second loop is probably the best choice.

```rust
fn test1() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    v.iter_mut().for_each(|e| {
        if *e <= 3 {
            let n = *e + 100;
            // v.push(n) // !!! INCORRECT !!!
            // we are trying to reallocate the storage while iterating over it
        } else {
            *e += 10;
        }
    });
    println!("{:?}", v);
}

fn test2() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    for i in 0..v.len() {
        let e = &mut v[i];
        if *e <= 3 {
            let n = *e + 100;
            v.push(n);
        } else {
            *e += 10;
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", v);
}

fn main() {
    test1(); // [1, 2, 3, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
    test2(); // [1, 2, 3, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 101, 102, 103]
}
```